# Node JS preventin users from deleting other user's products

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have a REST API built with Node JS and I'm currently using MongoDB as my database. I want to prevent the users from deleting another user's products and for this I checked if the userId from the decoded token is the same as the product userId.

Product schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    userId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    productImage: { type: String, required: false },
    category: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
      required: true
    },
    gender: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  { timestamps: { createdAt: "created_at" } }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

The delete product method:

```
  const id = req.params.productId;
  Product.findById({ _id: id }).then((product) => {
    if (product.userId != req.user._id) {
      return res.status(401).json("Not authorized");
    } else {
      Product.deleteOne({ _id: id })
        .exec()
        .then(() => {
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Product deleted succesfully",
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(500).json({
            error: err,
          });
        });
    }
  });
};
```

As you guys see first I'm searching executing the findByID method to access the userId property of the product, then I'm comparing the userId from the response with the userId from the decoded token.

I don't think my method is very efficient since it's running both findById and deleteOne methods.

Can you help me with finding a better solution for this?

Comment: It's an ok thing to do since you may want to notify your user that the product they are trying to remove does not exist, however you can always specify both userId and productId in `deleteOne` method.

Comment: One `findById` and one `deleteOne` isn't inefficient either. You're doing meaningless micro-optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Guy Incognito mentioned, what you are trying to do is an OK thing and you may want to keep it this way in case you want to send a 404 status stating the product they are trying to remove does not exist.

however, if you are trying to do it with only one request

```js
Product.deleteOne({ _id: id, userId: req.user._id })
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot to you and guy Incognito, it worked :)

Comment: Hey @typicallearner and @Guy Incognito. I updated my method like u said, like this: ```exports.deleteProduct = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  Product.deleteOne({ _id: id, userId: req.user._id }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json("Not authorized");
    }
    return res.status(200).json("Product deleted");
  });
};```, but I'm alwayt getting status 200 and the product is not being deleted. I thinks it's happening because the err parameter that I sent to the delete one callback function is null. Any idea how to fix this?